# Invisible element is detected as isDisplayed by Selenium WebDriver, Java

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following HTML code containing Form:

```
<div id="bodyLeftBlock" class="">
    <form id="signUpForm" class="" method="post" action="/en/signup/post/" novalidate="novalidate" style="display: none;">
        <input class="" type="hidden" value="am" name="systemsShortCutName">
        <label class="inputTitle translate" translatekey="NAME">Name</label>
        ....
        ....
```

Sometimes the form appears on the page, in this case `style="display: none;"` not presented on the page code.

When the Form is hidden, `style="display: none;"` is present in the code.

I need to distinguish is the Form presented or not.

Tried `driver.findElement(By.id("signUpForm")).isDisplayed`, `isEnabled` and some more options - never could distinguish by my code is Form presented or not.

What's wrong here, what's the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("signUpForm")).isDisplayed();
```

is definitely the most reliable and true way to define if element is visible or not.

Note that `isDisplayed()` has a quite complicated logic behind it, see: [Element Displayedness](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#dfn-element-displayed).

Among multiple "displayedness" indicators, there is:

> If the computed value of the display style property is "none", return false.

---

You can also try waiting for the `form` to become visible:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("signUpForm")));
```

or, invisible:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("signUpForm")));
```

Comment: Theoretically you are right, but in practice it doesn't work here. I don't know why. That's the problem exactly.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question when the form is hidden `style="display: none;"` presents in the code. But when the Form is displayed `style` not mentioned in the code at all.

Comment: @Eliyahu first of all, a sanity check: are you sure there is a single `form` element containing the `id="signUpForm"`?

Comment: @Eliyahu it could be that `style` is not explicitly set, but computed.

Comment: @Eliyahu thanks, is this a public site and you can share the link to it?

Comment: Maybe, the only thing I see is that `isDisplayed` (and other ways I tried) doesn't distinguish between the cases and I don't know how to  check this.

Comment: #5 of the doc really amazes me. Good stuff @alecxe

Comment: @Saifur thanks, yeah, the logic described in the paragraph is not something you can easily replicate..